# What is non-Coulomb force?

Tags: electromagnetism

It is my understanding that non-Coulomb E-field is generated by time varying flux of B. From this follows that non-Coulomb force is $F_{nc}=qE_{nc}$. But, when reading the paper by Sherwood, Chabay "A unified treatment of electrostatics and circuits" I get confused when they say that non-Coulomb field **is due to charges**.
Which is right, non-Coulomb field is due to changing B, or due to charges?

Comment: In my understanding, the Coulomb force is the force between **stationary** charges. Maybe what they mean in the paper is "_non-Coulumb field is due to moving charges_"?

Comment: I just had a look at the "paper" https://matterandinteractions.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/circuit.pdf The first time they speak about non-Coulomb forces, they write: "We introduce a 'mechanical battery' similar to a Van de Graaff generator, in which a conveyor belt applies a non-Coulomb force $F_{NC}$ to extract an electron from the positive plate ..." In this context non-Coulomb force has nothing to do with $dB/dt$. Hence, I believe it would be very helpful, if you could provide the exact quote you do not understand.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now I understand what authors meant by non- Coulomb force.